# how to set the springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path from application.properties

Tags: java, swagger-2.0

I am using Swagger2 in my Java based REST API. The basepath of the API has been set from the `application.properties` file

```
server.contextPath=/myapi/v1/
```

I could access the endpoints using my Swagger UI in localhost as in the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapi/v1/swagger-ui.html
```

And my end points work fine. But I am not able to access the JSON API doc from the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapi/v1/api-docs
```

The JSON API doc has been shown in:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapi/v1/v2/api-docs
```

An extra path `v2` is showing now. I read certain articles saying that this is because of the Swagger2 default api-docs path and we can override the path using  `springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path` property in application property.

How can I set the `v2` path to `http://localhost:8080/myapi/v1/api-docs`
? Through the `application.properties`? I have been trying different paths but not getting the right result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
server.contextPath=/MyAppName/v1
springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path=/api-docs
```

Setting the above application properties helped me getting the api-docs in right path

Comment: This made my day, Thanks !

Comment: glad to hear it helped. My next issue is creating swagger doc for two versions of service :) @VictorPetit